# Is there a way to do a nested FOR loop in Excel?

Tags: excel, for-loop

If have the following two columns with the values:

```
 A  B  
 1  1  
 2  2  
 3  3  
 4  4
```

How can I multiply and return the sum:

1* 1 + 1 * 2 + 1* 3 + 1 * 4 + 2 * 1 + 2 * 2 + ... 4 * 4

exactly like a nested FOR loop?

Similarly, how can I multiply and sum only when first column value is bigger than second:

2 * 1 + 3 * 1 + 3 * 2 + 4 * 1 + 4 * 2 + 4 * 3 ?

Comment: Sorry, I never coded in excel before. I was wondering if there is a formulaic way to do the tasks.

Comment: I just vaguely remembered this resemble a double for loop. Removed the vba tag( it appeared in recommendations)

Answer (score 0):

With formula I think what is required, assuming A1:E1 and A1:A4 as shown, may be:

(1) The sum of B1:E4 where B2 copied across and down is:

```
=$A2*B$1
```

Alternatively the array formula with layout as you show:

```
=SUM(MMULT(A2:A5,TRANSPOSE(B2:B5)))
```

answer `100`, and

(2) in B2 copied across and down and then B2:E4 summed:

```
=IF($A2>B$1,$A2*B$1,0)
```

answer `35`.

[image: SO34080915 example]

Comment: for (1) I had to include a $ for the cells ( for my layout).